# Android WebView image displayed partly

Tags: android, css, image, webview

I have a webview which opens a page that shows different images like a gallery.

The image is saved locally on an sdcard and is loaded through css with background-image: url(file://...).

This issue seems (not sure though) to be connected to Android's request for resources for some reason. The longer the OS needs resources the bigger the white (or black) band is.

This doesn't happen always in one test session and affects images randomly (in a cycle a certain image displays ok, in the next it doesn't). Also it seems to affect only images, displaying an iframe is always loaded normally.

I wouldn't have a problem if this happened for one second and then it would display normally, the problem is that the image stays like that until the next refresh of the webview.

android's version is 4.4.2. It is a mk808b plus device if any of this helps...

Any ideas on how to solve or somehow decrease the times this happens... anything really... except using imageview, I want to keep all in the webview. Any directions to follow for further debugging are also greatly appreciated.

Thank you for any help you can provide.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If it is possible I would try converting background images to a vectorial format (like SVG). Rendering should be easier and less memory hungry.

Comment: Are there any cons to using this approach? Other than the conversion happening on upload.

Comment: Drawbacks are greater computational cost (decompress an image to bitmap is straightforward respect draw an image following steps in a SVG) and less flexibility of vectorial images (complex images have a lot of steps and rendering require more time). I just did a benchmark with a WebView using the same image in svg format (http://demosthenes.info/assets/images/thumbnails/homer-simpson.svg) and in the png (http://postimg.org/image/4s9m7x931/). At the end I've the same amount of ram occupied but with png I've a big spike (2x) corresponding to decompression.

Comment: Since these images are jpegs with no compression, I suppose that it would for sure use more cpu. Anyway it is a direction at least... thank you!

Comment: I actually just realized that I can't automatically convert these jpg to svg... so this approach is not possible.

Comment: May you provide an html for example and give a report of memory usage of your app using android studio tools? There may be a memory leak and there a lot of stack overflow post related to it.

Comment: Take a look also for webview alternatives, they may be more memory efficient. For example, [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) with [XWalkView](https://crosswalk-project.org/apis/embeddingapidocs/reference/org/xwalk/core/XWalkView.html), copy and paste example here -> https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/embedding_crosswalk.html